# How to get rolling median on pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by, median, rolling-computation

```
Data:

              vix      s_0000     s_0001     s_0002     s_0003  s_0004  
Date                                                                     
1990-01-02  17.24         NaN  13.389421        NaN        NaN     NaN   
1990-01-03  18.19         NaN  13.588601        NaN        NaN     NaN   
1990-01-04  19.22         NaN  13.610730        NaN        NaN     NaN   
1990-01-05  20.11         NaN  13.477942        NaN        NaN     NaN   
1990-01-08  20.26         NaN  13.477942        NaN        NaN     NaN   
...           ...         ...        ...        ...        ...     ...   
2020-12-23  23.31  116.631310  22.171579  15.890000  16.577030    9.00   
2020-12-24  21.53  116.641243  21.912146  15.660000  16.606722    8.77   
2020-12-28  21.70  117.158287  22.191536  16.059999  16.200956    8.93   
2020-12-29  23.08  116.561714  21.991972  15.860000  16.745275    8.80   
2020-12-30  22.77  116.720795  22.899990  16.150000  17.932884    8.60
```

I would like to add a new column "HVM" showing a 12-month rolling median (n=12) of vix.
For instance, the HVM for January 1991 will be the median of Jan 1990 to Dec 1990. The HVM for February 1991 will be the median of Feb 1990 to Jan 1991. There will be no HVM for Year 1990. I've only managed the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
md = pd.read_csv('ADJ_CLOSE.zip')
md.Date = pd.to_datetime(md.Date)
md.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
md['HVM'] = md.groupby(md.Date.dt.year)['vix'].transform('median')
```

However this code applies the 12m median starting from 1990, which gives the same HVM for the entire year, instead of calculating from the past 12 months. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: had a look at [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html); like `.rolling(<settings>).median()`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `12M` is considered as a non-fixed frequency. The best you can do is to compute the median over 365 days:

```
md = pd.read_csv('ADJ_CLOSE.zip', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])
md['HVM'] = md.rolling('365D')['vix'].median()
```